# batchfiles eclipse main application external tools

Tags: eclipse, command-line, batch-file, external-tools

I am working with Lejos and java Eclipse on Windows 7. As my machine is 64 bit it will not allow me run the standard Lejos driver as an Eclipse plugin I installed it as an external tool . I followed this super helpfull tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEFA0DdFhm8  However for my project I need to be able to regularly send instructions to my Nxt brick. is there anyway that I can call external tools from the main application while it is running ??Alternatively is it possible to call batch files in main programs or even make command line arguments while a program is running ??? I have read allot of forums on this and no where have I found the solution to my problem, if people have any Idea I would appreciate the help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after allot of reading around there is and article on java world 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1
that sums up beautifully what you should and shouldn't do .. hope this is helpfull for anyone coming after me ......